# How to get the id of an anchor tag in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to get the id of an anchor tag in jQuery?
This is the tag.

```
 <ul class="formfield">
     <li class="selected"><a href="" id="text">Text</a></li>
     <li><a href="" id="textarea">Textarea</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I need to get the id, i.e., textarea,text etc in a variable.

I tried something like this,but there is no such thing as fieldValue I suppose.

```
$('.formfield a').click(function() {         
    fieldType=$('.formfield a').fieldValue();
    alert(fieldType);
});
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To get the `id` attribute of a field, you would do:

```
$('ul.formfield a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

To get the *text contents* of the a tags (the text between the opening and closing tags), you would do:

```
$('ul.formfield a').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert(text);
});
```

Please note the usage of `$(this)` inside the click function. You were re-using the selector which would not do what you want. Inside the event handler, `this` refers to the element being acted on, so with the code above you would get 'text' or 'textarea' depending on which one you clicked.

Comment: "this.id" would also have the value (it's standard for a DOM element)

Answer (score 2):

You said you want it in a variable?

Here you go:

```
var myvariable = $('ul.formfield a').attr('id');
```

It will give you the id of the first matched element, or in your example "text".

Comment: How to get a particular element by providing id? For example, if i need like this? id="textarea"

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet works for me.

```
<a id="56" class="slot">[01:40:00-01:45:00] </a>
$(".slot").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```